# Is the 'greatest negative number' indeterminate, not defined or doesn't exist?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let's take S as a set of negative real numbers.
Intuitively it seems that there's no greatest element in S because the term 'greatest' only makes sense if the set S is finite. But I don't know the exact term to describe this situation. How to describe the 'greatest negative number'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of a "greatest element" does not only make sense for finite sets, without defining posets, lets just focus on the real numbers:

> Given a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, a real number $x$ is said to be the maximum element of $A$ if
> \begin{align} &x\in A\\ 
> &\mbox{and} \\
> &\forall_{y\in A}[y\leq x] 
> \end{align}

(I hope you are familiar with quantifiers?)

Anyway, the set

$$ (-\infty,0) \cup \{1\} $$

has a maximum element, even though it has infinitely many elements.

Now to answer your question, the set of negative real numbers, $S$ does not have a maximum element, since if $a\in S$ were a maximum, then $\frac{a}{2}\in A$ but $a< \frac{a}{2}$ contradicting our assumption that $a$ was a maximum.

If you want to gain some more understanding, try to prove that if a subset of the real numbers has a maximum, then it is unique (this was implicitly assumed in the definition with the wording "*the* maximum"). For generalisations, that might help you answer questions like this in the future, look into the concept of a [poset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). (Beware that there is a difference between a maximal element, and an element which is the maximum, although the maximum is necessarily maximal, but the converse is not true in general)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is broadly correct here and raises an interesting point.

What the set $S$ is (letting $S$ be the set of all negative real numbers), is a set that is open on one side, more precisely there is no greatest element that you could write down that is a part of that set because I can always give you a slightly bigger number that is always in the set.

This also applies for any set of real numbers that is open on one side, say the set $J=[0,1)$. The square bracket indicates that $0\in J$ and the round bracket indicates that $1\notin J$. So here we have the same problem when it comes to defining the greatest element of $J$.

It is clear that it doesn't really make sense to define the largest number of $S$ or $J$ but it does make sense to define a smallest upper bound as follows. The least upper bound or supremum of any non-empty set $K$ that is bounded above is defined as the smallest real number $x$ such that $x\geq a$ for all $a\in K$ and, for all $\epsilon >0,\; x-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound.

For the set $S$, this would be $0$ and for $J$, it would be $1$.

Comment: first half of the answer is useful, thanks. While defining Supremum, I think it will be more clear and correct if you add two more conditions: `set K being a non empty set` and `x >= a, for all a in K`

Comment: @rangen1 Take $K=[0,1]$ and an arbitrary $x\le 1\,.$ Since $x-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $K$ it follows that your supremum is $-\infty.$ Absurd.

Comment: Definition of supremum was rushed and not rigorous thanks for pointing that out. I believe it is fixed.

Comment: sup$K$ is the smallest real number $x$ such that $x\ge a$ for all $a\in K\,.$ Period. You do not need that part with $\epsilon\,.$ Please read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum).

Comment: @KurtG.  "smallest" and "for all $x -\epsilon$ are not" are equivalent statements and the very definition of "smallest".  IMO the clearest definition for supremum is that we define $\sup K$ as an upper bound and any $d < \sup K$ is not. I wouldn't bother with $x-\epsilon$ as that's confusing but, I've found just specifying $x$ is the smallest that is $x\ge a$ for all $a \in K$ and leaving it at that sometimes goes over a students head.